# SQL Server connection user varies when using '127.0.0.1' vs 'localhost'. Why?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, database-connection

When I attempt to connect to my local, default SQL Server instance via SQL Management studio using Windows Authentication, I successfully connect when I use Server Name "localhost", but fail when I use Server Name "127.0.0.1". With login auditing enabled for both failed and successful logins, I see that the successful logins are recorded as:

> Login succeeded for user 'AzureAD\RealUsername'. Connection made using Integrated Authentication. [CLIENT: < local machine >]

And the failed logins are recorded as:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]

Possibly relevant:

- I can connect using the ip address if I use SQL Server authentication (since I am forcing it to use an existing login).
- There is no entry in my hosts file for "localhost", and when I ping localhost it does resolve to 127.0.0.1.
- The SQL instance uses port 1433.
- The issue, with very little variation, persists when connecting via SQL Management Studio, a .NET web app running in a local IIS instance, or via UDL file on my desktop.

**Here is my question:** Why would changing only the server value ('localhost' vs '127.0.0.1') change the identity used when connecting?

Comment: it's probably trying to use a different protocol (which is not enabled on the server). Does the server instance use the default port ? (1433)

Comment: might be of interest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks, @MitchWheat. I updated the question to indicate my instance does use port 1433 (I checked to be sure), and I will find some time to follow the steps in the doc you included. I'll post if anything fruitful comes of it!